# modify variable on main thread C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sockets

I am doing a deletion in an array when a socket connection has been terminated.I am kindoff working on a little chat program.i am deleting an element from an array of User objects.

```
public class User
{

    private Thread clthread;
    private string name;
    private Socket sock;

    public User(string _name, Thread _thread, Socket _sock)
    {
        sock = socket();
        clthread = _thread;
        name = _name;
        sock = _sock;
    }

    private Socket socket()
    {
        return new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }//initiaza socket nou

    public Thread CLThread
    {
        get { return clthread; }
        set { clthread = value; }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public Socket Sock
    {
        get { return sock; }
        set { sock = value; }
    }

}
```

the array is declared like this:

```
   User[] connected = new User[1024];
```

and this is how i am deleting

```
            private void Disconnection(int id)
    {
        User client = connected[id];
        for (int i = id; i < no - 1; i++)
        {
            connected[i] = connected[i + 1];
        }
        client.Sock.Close();
        client.CLThread.Abort();


        no--;
        MessageBox.Show(no.ToString());
        //ui clean

    }
```

The problem is that the counter for the user array is declared in the main wpf window.but i am executing the deletion method(Disconnection) in the threa associated to each socket.

Help?

Comment: do you talk about multiple threads in one application or about aultple applications that connect to one main application?

Comment: cant you use List<User> instead array? then you don't need to have counter of array.

Comment: one application, multiple threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this entire method needs to be serialized because you are also changing the array of clients:

```
object locker = new object(); // globally visible lock

...

private void Disconnection(int id)
{        
    lock(locker)
    {
        User client = connected[id];
        for (int i = id; i < no - 1; i++)
        {
            connected[i] = connected[i + 1];
        }
        client.Sock.Close();
        client.CLThread.Abort();

        no--;      
        MessageBox.Show(no.ToString());
    }
    //ui clean

}
```

And please see if you can change the array to something more efficient! Not only do you have to manually keep track of the counter, but deleting from an array is an O(n) operation.

Comment: i think this helped and also i was killing the thread before i was decrementing the no(no--).so apparently i was stopping the thread from where i wanted to decrement before i actually did it.Thanks a lot!

Comment: oh and i will try to do something more efficient.It was just what i first had i mind.Any suggestions on how to do it more efficiently?

Comment: @ALex Popa: You could try to use a `Dictionary<int, User>` data structure instead, mapping an id to a User. Searching and deleting from a hash table is constant (amortized) time.

Answer (score 2):

Use the lock around the counter for the user array because you are decrementing it from more than one thread.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly answering your question directly, because I just have a few points to bring up.

First, why not use automatic properties?  Instead of:

```
public Thread CLThread
{
    get { return clthread; }
    set { clthread = value; }
}
```

try

```
public Thread CLThread { get; set; }
```

You can do this for all of your properties.

Also, you're exposing the details of a disconnection externally.  You should have a public `Close()` method in your `User` class that deals with closing sockets and aborting threads.

That said, aborting threads is evil.  You should use an approach like having the thread return gracefully when an event gets signaled, and then call the thread's `Join()` method in `Close()` to wait for the thread to exit.

I agree with Reniuz -- use a `List<User>` instead and avoid managing the counter yourself.